# How to blacklist spam emails with forged addresses?

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention, blacklist

I have been receiving spam emails from forged addresses to my Hotmail account. They are filtered and classified as junk. Here is a message source from one spam message:

```
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtTQ0w9Ng==
X-Message-Status: n
X-SID-PRA: oebqhvii@yahoo.com
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-Message-Info: M98loaK0Lo27IVRxloyPIehL82TBCBZznyDVOtryad/VIplAa6+fKNc3Rs3nI6UPfEUu4gPPV+Z/BeuHLBJ9eFsqpejw5E/rGidVAAZzzI4=
Received: from 85-222-126-144.home.aster.pl ([85.222.126.44]) by COL0-MC2-F1.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
     Fri, 27 May 2011 11:20:52 -0700
Received: from [165.134.185.135] ([162.100.153.169] helo=localhost.localdomain)
    by smtpn.cwbhsx.com (envelope-from <oebqhvii@yahoo.com>)
    (ecelerity 3.0.22.977202 r(79488)) with ESMTP
    id 30eE-275-9704e066Y5; Fri, 27 May 2011 08:16:23 +0100
To:xxxx@xxxxx.com
Message-Id: <201105271820.UOQAZ628@2vuqmzc.com>
Date: Fri, 27 May 2011 08:12:21 +0100
Sender: oebqhvii@yahoo.com
From: "Gucci Louis.Vuitton" <oebqhvii@yahoo.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Subject: Replica-SHOP : Luxury Watches, Bags, Shoes
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Return-Path: oebqhvii@yahoo.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 27 May 2011 18:20:52.0745 (UTC) FILETIME=[D0054790:01CC1C9A]
```

What I want is to **blacklist** these spam messages to never receive them at all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Contact your ISP and see if they can/will do anything about it.
2. Buy a domain from a registrar that provides email services that include a mail server on which you can do sender address verification (either you have full admin control over the SMTP server and can install / configure as you wish, or their provided solution allows you, or them, to set up sender address verification.  This solution is the somewhat technical, but probably the best choice.
3. Buy a domain and set up your own server and set the DNS servers at the registrar for your domain to point to your DNS server, then set up an SMTP server as you see fit.  This is the most tedious option and will require a lot of technical knowledge to keep your server from becoming part of the problem.  Setting up a server from scratch means you will need to make certain it is secure and remains so via updates and applying security patches.  You need to absolutely make sure your SMTP server is not an "open relay" meaning anyone can use it to send mail as the spammers will take advantage of it within hours if not minutes of it becoming an open relay.  Your SMTP server should only accept email for deliver from inside your domain to outside your domain or outside your domain to inside your domain.  An open relay will accept mail for delivery from outside your domain to outside your domain.  Don't do that.  Also, your DNS records need to be set up properly for many other domains' SMTP mail servers to consider your SMTP mail server worthy of sending and receiving mail to and from.

Answer (score 0):

As a user of a web-based email service?  I don't believe this is possible.  Dynamic blacklisting of this type typically requires sever-level access to configure things like SPF or RBLs.